# How can I make the output from tapply() into a data.frame

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data.frame in R that looks like this:

```
      score    rms  template   aln_id       description
1  -261.410  4.951 2f22A.pdb  2F22A_1 S_00001_0000002_0
2  -231.987 21.813 1wb9A.pdb  1WB9A_4 S_00002_0000002_0
3  -263.722  4.903 2f22A.pdb  2F22A_3 S_00003_0000002_0
4  -269.681 17.732 1wbbA.pdb  1WBBA_6 S_00004_0000002_0
5  -258.621 19.098 1rxqA.pdb  1RXQA_3 S_00005_0000002_0
6  -246.805  6.889 1rxqA.pdb 1RXQA_15 S_00006_0000002_0
7  -281.300 16.262 1wbdA.pdb 1WBDA_11 S_00007_0000002_0
8  -271.666  4.193 2f22A.pdb  2F22A_2 S_00008_0000002_0
9  -277.964 13.066 1wb9A.pdb  1WB9A_5 S_00009_0000002_0
10 -261.024 17.153 1yy9A.pdb  1YY9A_2 S_00001_0000003_0
```

I can calculate summary statistics on the data.frame like this:

```
> tapply( d$score, d$template, mean )
1rxqA.pdb 1wb9A.pdb 1wbbA.pdb 1wbdA.pdb 1yy9A.pdb 2f22A.pdb 
-252.7130 -254.9755 -269.6810 -281.3000 -261.0240 -265.5993
```

Is there an easy way that I coerce this output back into a data.frame? I'd like for it to have these two columns:

```
d$template
mean
```

I love tapply, but right now I'm cutting and pasting the results from tapply into a text file and hacking it up a bit to get the summary statistics that I want with appropriate names. This feels very wrong, and I'd like to do something better!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d, "template", summarise, mean = mean(score))
```

Comment: This will work, but plyr tends to be very slow on large datasets. In my experience, aggregate, described below, is much more efficient.

Comment: That's a reasonable comment, as plyr is much more flexible than aggregate.  And future versions will hopefully be faster.

Answer (score 32):

There are a lot of different ways to transform the output from a *tapply* call into a data.frame.

But it's much simpler to *avoid* the call to *tapply* in the first place and substitute that with a call to a similar function that returns a *data frame* instead of a vector:

more specifically:

- *tapply* returns a vector
- ***aggregate*** returns a data frame

so just change your function call from *tapply* to **aggregate**, like so:

```
data(iris)     # in 'datasets' just call 'data' and pass in 'iris' as an argument

tx = tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), mean)
# returns: versicolor  virginica 
             5.94       6.59 

class(tx)
# returns: vector

tx = aggregate(iris$Sepal.length, list(iris$Species), mean)
# returns:
         Group.1    x
     1 versicolor 5.94
     2  virginica 6.59


class(tx)
# returns: data.frame
```

Comment: genius. This is the answer!

Comment: (+1) You might also consider adding the formula method to your answer.  I think it's much cleaner and the column names don't get changed.  `aggregate(score ~ template, d, mean)`

Comment: When using the formula, if you are interested in `summary` and want to count the number of `NA`'s: `aggregate(score ~ template, data=d, FUN=summary, na.rm=FALSE, na.action=na.pass)`

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
mn <- tapply(d$score,d$template,mean)
df <- data.frame(template=names(mn),mean=mn)
```

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` is a good option for this specific example, but more generally:

```r
as.data.frame.list(tapply(d$score, d$template, mean))
#   X1rxqA.pdb X1wb9A.pdb X1wbbA.pdb X1wbdA.pdb X1yy9A.pdb X2f22A.pdb
# 1   -252.713  -254.9755   -269.681     -281.3   -261.024  -265.5993
```

A faster option would be:

```r
data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(d$score, d$template, mean, simplify = F)))
#   X1rxqA.pdb X1wb9A.pdb X1wbbA.pdb X1wbdA.pdb X1yy9A.pdb X2f22A.pdb
# 1   -252.713  -254.9755   -269.681     -281.3   -261.024  -265.5993
```

**Benchmark**

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  as.data.frame.list = as.data.frame.list(tapply(d$score, d$template, mean)),
  do.call = data.frame(do.call(cbind, tapply(d$score, d$template, mean, simplify = F)))
)
# Unit: microseconds
#               expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval cld
# as.data.frame.list 408.0 411.40 418.341 414.95 418.20 481.0   100  a 
#            do.call 185.8 191.15 202.398 197.25 202.15 321.6   100   b
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `array2DF`:

```r
array2DF(tapply(d$score, d$template, mean), responseName = "template")
#        Var1  template
# 1 1rxqA.pdb -252.7130
# 2 1wb9A.pdb -254.9755
# 3 1wbbA.pdb -269.6810
# 4 1wbdA.pdb -281.3000
# 5 1yy9A.pdb -261.0240
# 6 2f22A.pdb -265.5993
```